# How to write a pandas Series to CSV as a row, not as a column?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I need to write a `pandas.Series` object to a CSV file as a row, not as a column. Simply doing

```
the_series.to_csv( 'file.csv' )
```

gives me a file like this:

```
record_id,2013-02-07
column_a,7.0
column_b,5.0
column_c,6.0
```

What I need instead is this:

```
record_id,column_a,column_b,column_c
2013-02-07,7.0,5.0,6.0
```

This needs to work with pandas 0.10, so using `the_series.to_frame().transpose()` is not an option.

Is there a simple way to either transpose the Series, or otherwise get it written as a row?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can just use the DataFrame constructor (rather than to_frame):

```
In [11]: pd.DataFrame(s).T
Out[11]: 
record_id   column_a  column_b  column_c
2013-02-07         7         5         6
```

Comment: It seems like there should be an orient arg for Series.to_csv.

Comment: This seems to be outdated. I'm still searching for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want line breaks:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'record_id' : ['column_a','column_b','column_c'],
                       '2013-02-07' : [7.0, 5.0, 6.0]})
    str_1 = ', '.join(df.record_id.tolist())
    str_2 = ', '.join(str(x) for x  in df['2013-02-07'].tolist())

    print('record_id, ' + str_1)
    print('2013-02-07, ' + str_2)
```