# write pandas series column wise instead of row wise

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 1 dimensional series and need to write it to excel.
I have used:

```
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
series.to_excel(writer, index=True, sheet_name='Final')
```

but this prints the result row wise and I need the result column-wise.
I have tried .transpose(), but for a series the transpose is self and i only get the row wise result again.

Comment: IIUC, try converting to a dataframe and transpose `series.to_frame().T.to_excel....`

Comment: Maybe try axis=1?

Comment: You can find the answer to the similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320405/how-to-write-a-pandas-series-to-csv-as-a-row-not-as-a-column